# String constant and Character constant

Tags: c, string, char, printf

```
int main(){
   printf("the value is %d \n  " ,'x'+ "x");

   return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> 4196024

But the former one (`'x'`) is an integer and latter one (`"x"`)is a string .

Can I know how ? Or is it giving me a garbage value.

Comment: Answer(s) below. Yes, it is giving you a garbage value. But the real question is, what are you attempting to do here? `%d` prints an integer, but neither `'x'` nor `"x"` are integers. What kind of outcome did you expect?

Comment: @MrLister: `'x'` is a value of type `int`. You can use it to add to an address.

Comment: 'x' is a character constant. It is an integer only

Comment: I know, but you haven't said what kind of result you wanted. What is it that you're trying to display? The ASCII values of both characters? (That would have been 120 and 120.) The sum of the ASCII values? (That would have been -16.)

Comment: Nope, i was just trying to see what error i will get . But specifying there "%d gave me a integer value. I noticed that when you said me !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 4):

Literal strings have type `char [N]` where `N` is just large enough for all characters in the literal plus the terminating `'\0'` (namely `"x"` has type `char[2]`).

In the context of the expression `'x' + "X"`, the array gets converted to a pointer to its first element, then that address is added with the `int` value `'x'`. The resulting address is passed on to `printf()` with an invalid conversion specification.

You have invoked Undefined Behaviour!

Try this

```
printf("the valus is %p\n", (void*)('x' + "x"));
```

Also note that the address `'x' + "x"` is not part of any object in your program. Merely evaluating it is already Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Sir, printing the address is also UB? I thought accessing will be UB. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: evaluating `"x" + N` where `N < 0` or `N > 2` invokes UB. You need to evaluate it before printing. Imagine `"x"[2]` is at the end of memory (at `0xff...fff`) --- `"x"[3]` will overflow :-)

Comment: Sorry sir, but is `"x"[2]` and `"x" + N` are same? i thought it will be `*("x" + N)`.

Comment: Not the same: I was sloppy. The address calculations are the same though

Comment: but as long as we're not de-referencing, we should be ok, no? that's just the addition of an integer with a _valid_ pointer, the result being another pointer. Untll we access the memory thtought that resultant pointer , it should be ok.....Am i right?

Comment: Evaluating `0xff...fff + 1` generates overflow, overflow is UB. One of the good things about UB is that computers will do sensible things when presented with a construct that will never invoke that UB.

Comment: Just in case, if I assign the pointer to `uintptr_t` and then perform the addition, I can get rid of the UB, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I believe so. `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer type, and overflow on unsigned integers is defined to wrap. You can't convert it back to a pointer after that though. (Also, note that on any compiler that actually exists, `'x'+"X"` is probably fine, if you're just doing this once as an experiment)

Comment: @immibis Thank you. The last sentence was all I needed to know, (a tleast, in this case, it's fine).. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh pointer arithmetic is only defined within bounds of an object. See C11 6.5.6/8

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks sir. Looking into it now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically,

```
 printf("the value is %d \n  " ,'x'+ "x");
```

invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What you need is `%p` format specifier here.

Otherwise, **in general,**

- `"string"` gives you the base address of the string literal
- `'p'` gives you the ASCII value of the `char` representation.

So, what essentially is being done here is to print the address of the member in `'x'`th element of the string `"x"` (which does not make much sense, practically).

For better understanding, you can re-write the print statement as

```
printf("the pointer is %p\n", (void *) ("x"+ 'x'));
```

which is equivalent to

```
printf("the pointer is %p\n", (void *) &("x"['x']));
```

Note that you don't need spaces before or after the newline in the print format.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for in the formatted string is an integer so it is printing the integer value of the character `'x'` added to the base address of the string literal `"x"`.

`'x'` is 120 so if you use a memory viewer to peek at the outputted value minus 120 bytes, you will probably find an `'x'` followed by a `'\0'` (= 0).